# How to make some parameter in yang model as read only

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I have one yang model, which is use to change run time parameter of my application.how i can make some parameter read only because some parameter when get change it impact on my code.I want user cannot change that parameter on run time.

```
    notification bind-lne-name-failed {
    description
      "Indicates an error in the association of an interface to an
       LNE. Only generated after success is initially returned when
       bind-lne-name is set.";
    leaf name {
      type leafref {
        path "/if:interfaces/if:interface/if:name";
      }
      mandatory true;
      description
        "Contains the interface name associated with the
         failure.";
    }
    leaf bind-lne-name {
      type leafref {
        path "/if:interfaces/if:interface/lne:bind-lne-name";
      }
      mandatory true;
      description
        "Contains the bind-lne-name associated with the
         failure.";
    }
    leaf error-info {
      type string;
      description
        "Optionally, indicates the source of the assignment
         failure.";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this Question have anything to do with either [java] or [go].   Is it even a programming question?  Would it be better on ServerFault?

Comment: @StephenC this is yang specific question , but i am unable to find tag related to this one. Please suggest

Comment: I have retagged your question.   In future, don't pick tags at random.  It will get *the wrong kind of attention* to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided a YANG notification, which defines the structure of messages being sent from a YANG-capable server (for example, a NETCONF server) to a YANG-capable client (a NETCONF client) that has subscribed to it.
So notifications doesn't describe configuration data, but something the server sends to the client on its own.

I assume you have another yang model that does contain the data you want, which might overlap with the notification data.

Generically, you make leafs non-configurable by using the **config** keyword, which can have true or false values.
Here's an example on how that would look like in the error-info leaf:

```
    leaf error-info {
      type string;
      config false;
      description
        "Optionally, indicates the source of the assignment
         failure.";
    }
```

By default, every data nodes are **config true**, meaning that they are writable, so that can be ommitted. For defining read-only data, you use **config false**.

You can find documentation on this keyword on the YANG RFC at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.19.1